# Finding highest volume of sales in linked list C

Tags: c, struct

I'm new here so please bear with me as I explain my problem

I am trying to create a function in which finds the day in which had the most sales. I am doing this by reading in the data from a file which contains:

```
date, item, count
```

I am using a linked list which filters through all the sales structs within the linked list ( they are ordered by date )

**Here is my struct:**

```
typedef struct sales {
    int amount;
    char *date;
    struct stockItem *item;
    struct sales *next;
} sales;
```

**Here is the code for finding which day had the most sales:**

```
sales *sFirstNode = NULL;
sales *sLastNode = NULL;

int findHighestVolumeSales() {
        char *previousDate = NULL;
        struct sales *tmpPtr = sFirstNode;
        struct sales *tmpNxt = sFirstNode->next;
        char *currentDate = tmpPtr->date;
        int tmp=0;
        int mostSales;
        while(tmpNxt != NULL){
               while(tmpNxt != tmpPtr){
                        if(currentDate == previousDate){
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount + tmp;
                         }
                         else{
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount;
                         }
                         if(tmp > mostSales){
                            mostSales = tmp;
                            printf("%d\n", mostSales);
                         }
                        previousDate = tmpPtr->date;
                        tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
                }
                tmpPtr = sFirstNode;
                tmpNxt = tmpNxt->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", mostSales);
        return mostSales;
    }
```

The values the function returns seems to be that of an address rather than the mostSales itself.

**I'm getting:**

```
6421718
```

The values are big, but not as big as this. I'm certain theres a problem with my code

EDIT:

```
int findHighestVolumeSales() {
        char *previousDate = NULL;
        struct sales *tmpPtr = sFirstNode;
        struct sales *tmpNxt = sFirstNode->next;
        char *currentDate = NULL;
        int tmp=0;
        int mostSales =0;
        while(tmpNxt != NULL){
               currentDate = tmpPtr->date;
               while(tmpNxt != tmpPtr){
                       // printf("%d \n", mostSales);
                        if(currentDate == previousDate){
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount + tmp;
                         }
                         else{
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount;
                         }
                         if(tmp > mostSales){
                            mostSales = tmp;
                            printf("%d\n", mostSales);
                         }
                        previousDate = tmpPtr->date;
                        tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
                }
                tmpPtr = sFirstNode;
                tmpNxt = tmpNxt->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", mostSales);
        return mostSales;// Place holder
    }
```

Comment: Just from this can see only uninitialized pointers being dereferenced .

Comment: Why do you `typedef` `sales` if you use the `struct` namespace anyway?

Comment: @Olaf I know I've done this in multiple places in my code, was planning on going back and sorting through it nearer to finishing

Comment: I presume you are accumulating sales fom several records of the same date, and restarting at the next record in the list. If so, `tmp=0` must be moved inside the first `while` loop, and the date to match must be initialised inside that loop too..

Comment: Where is that @ameyCU

Comment: Why inside the first while loop @WeatherVane

Comment: Otherwise you'll include the sales of another date.

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because apparently you store the dates as strings, and are attempting to compare those strings with `==`. But without an MCVE, it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: But I have `if(currentDate == previousDate){
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount + tmp;
                         }
                         else{
                                tmp = tmpPtr->amount;
                         }` @WeatherVane

Comment: oh absolutely! I should be using strcmp right @user3386109

Comment: Yes, but, you didn't update `currentDate` at the same time. Rethink of the logic is possibly required.

Comment: currentDate is never changing..

Comment: Well spotted @Ravi Thank you

Comment: So just below the first while loop I have added `currentDate = tmpPtr->date` @WeatherVane

Comment: Your example is not going to compile so debugging it is pointless ie I cannot tell if the error is because the code is wrong or the question.

Comment: It compiles I just get the wrong values @Harry

Comment: It does not compile for me either.  Aparrently, there is no main().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the list is arranged in date order, you don't even need two nested loops. Also, you neglected to initialise `mostSales = 0;` I continued to test for date pointer equality, but it is not said what it means. You might need fixed char arrays for the dates.

```
int findHighestVolumeSales() {
    struct sales *tmpPtr = sFirstNode;
    char *currentDate;                          // perhaps array is needed
    char *mostDate;                             // ditto
    int tmp = 0;
    int mostSales = INT_MIN;                    // <<-- initialise !!!

    if(tmpPtr == NULL) {                        // the empty list
        return 0;
    }
    mostDate = currentDate = tmpPtr->date;      // perhaps strcpy()

    while(tmpPtr != NULL){                      // parse the list
        if(tmpPtr->date != currentDate) {       // perhaps strcmp(), don't know
            if(mostSales <= tmp) {              // check the max
                mostSales = tmp;                // stamp
                mostDate = currentDate;         // perhaps strcpy()
            }
            tmp = 0;                            // reset
            currentDate = tmpPtr->date;         // perhaps strcpy() to fixed array
        }
        tmp += tmpPtr->amount;                  // accumulate sales
        tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;                  // advance
    }

    // check loose end
    if(mostSales <= tmp) {              // check the max
        mostSales = tmp;                // stamp
        mostDate = currentDate;         // perhaps strcpy()
    }

    printf("%d on %s\n", mostSales, mostDate);  // report
    return mostSales;
}
```

Comment: Why have you made tmp =0 in the while loop? wouldn't this only allow for 2 consecutive dates? Check my updated edit, I believe mine works

Comment: Because the date changed.

Comment: Given that `amount` is of a signed type, the way you calculate the maximum could be incorrect if the last nodes belonging to a date are negative.

Comment: @EOF you mean refunds were issued? OK, `int mostSales = INT_MIN;`

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure, or maybe items of negative value were sold (perhaps payment for disposal of harmful substances).

Comment: @EOF edited thank you.

Comment: @Blarsssss if you believe your works, what are you asking that caused me this effort? Yours will not work, since `mostSales` is not initialisaed.

Comment: I just finished it when you posted the answer, I'm just asking does mine look like it would work? @WeatherVane Also I'm very grateful for your answer

Comment: @EOF the records are in date order. And it is you who wants to account for negative sales. If *they* were the max, I would close the shop ;)

Comment: @Blarsssss you are asking *will your edit work?* I have already said, only one loop is needed.

Comment: Yours is printing 109725 also @WeatherVane

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: 26  @WeatherVane It has chosen the correct date

Comment: Like is it printing the address or something @WeatherVane

Comment: I'm  printing out each time it updates the mostSales. I am getting these values 5,5,5,5,5,5,5 109725

Comment: @Blarsssss I am sorry you are getting that. I wrote this "blind" as I do not have a data structure to test it from. Is there a possibility that you are using a slightly different method from me, that builds and reports the data with the same "quirk"? What happens if you print the sales (`amount`) in *every* loop, in this code?

Comment: The same thing happens, getting the same results

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked you just to print the `amount` field, with a view to spotting any rogues.

Comment: Actually I get 109642
109645
109647
109654
109662
109666
109671
109673
109678
109686
109688
109693
109696
109697
109699
109701
109706
109710
109717
109725
109725 @WeatherVane

Comment: Please show me your `printf` statement.

Comment: @WeatherVane `tmp += tmpPtr->amount;                  // accumulate sales
        printf("%d\n", tmp);
        tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;                  // advance`

Comment: I was expecting to see `printf("%d\n", tmpPtr->amount);` placed right at the top of the `while` loop. This is simple list parse, and it will show all your sales amounts, quite apart from my maxing code. In fact, for this exercise you can cut out everything between that and the `tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;`

Comment: if(mostSales <= tmp) condition is never true, but it is looking at my results

Comment: These are the values I get posting the printf at the top of the while loop 2
8
8
3
2
8
5
5
5
1
4
1
2
2
1
8
7
4
5
8
6
6
8
4 @WeatherVane

Comment: In that case I can only guess you have some undefined behaviour over the way you are handling the date.

Comment: Are the currentDate and tmpPtr-date pointing to the same thing? I can't understand why this is never true..   `if(tmpPtr->date != currentDate) `

Comment: Still stuck on this problem, It is also never printing out the last tmpPtr->amount @WeatherVane

Comment: I fixed it, was inserting the data all wrong, thank you for your patience and help @WeatherVane